# Catching exception from out of index

Tags: c++, class, exception, try-catch

I have some main file which i can not edit. There are some things to be done and i am writing classes suitable to main file. v1 object is an instance of my own vector class.

At some point of main i have this line.

```
try {
    // trying to get the element at(4)
    // should give an error
    cout << v1[4] << endl;
} catch (const string & err_msg) {
    cout << err_msg << endl;
}
```

My v1 vector's size is "3" so program is crashing because i am going out of index. Taking error is ok here. But how can i get an exception for cout line before program crashes ? And i am not allowed to edit that main code. I need to do something with my header files or class definitions. Thanks.

Comment: So you have a class of your own and `v1` is an instance of your class? Can you show your definition of `operator []`?

Comment: If `v1` is an `std::vector` then you are stuck. You have to modify the code.

Comment: @AndyProwl do i need to overload [] ? I didn't do anything special for that operator. All i do is creating a v1 vector on my own.

Comment: @juanchopanza i created my own vector class inheriting STL vector. Isn't there anything to do for this step ?

Comment: @Akeara: Standard containers are not meant to be derived from. Can you post the whole program and tell exactly what you are and are not allowed to change?

Comment: As has been mentioned before, it is not a good idea to publicly inherit from `std::vector`. But you can overload `operator[]` and call vector's `at()` function. That will throw for out of bounds access.

Comment: @juanchopanza: But that will not throw an `std::string` (fortunately). The OP is mentioning he can't modify the posted code, and there the `catch` handler is catching an `std::string`

Comment: @AndyProwl good point. I would just throw the code away. I don't know if that counts as modifying :)

Comment: @juanchopanza: Perhaps it does, but I agree ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without modifying the main code, you should write your own vector class which check bounds in `operator[]`.

Something like:

```
template <typename T>
class MyVector
{
  T *data;
  int length;

  ...

  T &operator[](int i)
  {
    if (i < 0 || i >= length)
       throw std::string("Out of bounds!"); //throw std::out_of_range;
    else
       return data[i];
  }
  ...
};
```

Otherwise if you're using `std::vector`, you can use [`at`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/at) instead of `[]`:

> Returns a reference to the element at specified location pos. Bounds
>   checking is performed, exception of type std::out_of_range will be
>   thrown on invalid access.

Comment: so what i understand here is; i need to overload [] using at() function to check for index boundary. Overload method body will throw exception before cout gives an error, right ?

Comment: If you're writing your own vector, yes overload `operator[]`. If you're using `std::vector` simply ise `at` method which throws `std::out_of_range`.

Comment: @M M. its working perfectly when its out of bounds. but when i try it with v1[2] for example; i get unhandled exception error. Is the return type `data[i];` true  with `T *data;` ?

Comment: Yes, it's true. and, I just changed `i>length` to `i>=length`.

Comment: no i mean what if i dont want to get error using v1[2] ? it gives that error.

Comment: What's the length of allocate array? How do you constructing your vector?

Comment: @M M. length is 3 in my case. When i type 2 its between bounds but still crashes. I implement like this.

`ArithmeticVector(T n) 
 {

  ArithmeticVector::resize(n);

  T random[100];
  for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
   random[i]=rand()%10;
  }
  ArithmeticVector::assign(random,random + int(n));
 };

 void print(){
  ArithmeticVector<T>::iterator it;
  for (it=ArithmeticVector::begin(); it!=ArithmeticVector::end(); it++){
    cout << ' ' << *it;
 cout << '\n';}
 };`

Comment: @Akeara: I guess you have another problem, ask your new problem in StackOverflow.